# Concurrent http requests using a blocking http library with Python in a single thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency, nonblocking, python-asyncio

So I have this problem I am trying to solve in a particular way, but I am not sure how hard it is to achieve.

I would like to use the asyncio/coroutines features of Python 3.4 to trigger many concurrent http requests using a blocking http library, like requests, or any Python api that does http requests like boto for aws.

I know about run_in_executor() method to run tasks in threads/processes, but I would like to avoid that.

I would like to do it in a single-thread, using those select features in Linux/Unix kernel.

Actually I was following David Beazley's presentation on this, and I was trying to use this code: https://github.com/dabeaz/concurrencylive/blob/master/aserver.py

but without the future/pool stuff, and use my blocking-api call instead of computing the Fibonacci number.

Put it seems that the http requests are still running in sequence.

Any ideas if this is possible? And how?

Thanks

Comment: why don't you want to use run_in_executor() ?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, no practical reason. I want to learn how this thing works, and if it's possible to run what I have described it in the same thread, using some socket tricks or whatever to wrap the blocking call. And if not, why not. Basically I want to understand how it works exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible. All the calls that the `requests` library makes to the underlying socket are blocking (i.e. `socket.read`) because the socket is in blocking mode. You could put the socket into non-blocking mode, but then `socket.read` would fail. You basically need an event-loop to tell you when it's possible to do a `socket.read`, but blocking libraries aren't written with one in mind. This is the whole reason why `asyncio` exists; providing a default event-loop that different libraries can share and make use of non-blocking file descriptors (e.g. sockets).

Use `aiohttp`, it's just as *easy* as `requests` and in the process you get to learn more about `asyncio`. `asyncio` and the new Python 3.5 `async/await` syntax are the Future of networking IO; yield to it (pun intended).

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for. I did a quick test with aiohttp, and it looked really really good.